# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertCSS')" Chrome Extension Manifest 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and I want to change the tab's css, but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertCSS')

Here is my script:

```js
applybtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
        target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
        files: ["/src/themes/test.css"]
    });
});
```

Comment: To use it you need to add "scripting" permission as shown in the first section of the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/).

Answer (score 0):

Usually this sort of error pops up because the "scripting" permission is not given to the extension. So you should add the permission in your `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "Scripting Extension",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"],
  ...
}
```